# Every command returns error in Rhel

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rhel, rhel7

I am using SSH to connect a remote server. I did some installations and wanted to test whether they start after reboot. I rebooted the machine with sudo reboot. SSH session dropped. I reconnected. After login, every command I type, whether it is valid or not returns following output.

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: tty: command not found
-bash: uname: command not found
-bash: whoami: command not found
-bash: sed: command not found
-bash: logger: command not found
```

What to do to get rid of this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Print the value of PATH before running commands

Comment: likely due to `$PATH` variable corrupted. Try logging in as `root` using `su -m` and try editing the `.bashrc`  to fix the `$PATH` variable as a `root` user.

Comment: @Aaron: I wasn't then but I am now :)

Comment: @Aaron I wouldn't expect either `echo` nor `printf` to have that problem as they are both shell builtins (for `bash` at least) and so wouldn't be affected by a corrupted `PATH`

Comment: @EricRenouf woops you're right, I thought about builtins but was sure some of the commands posted were too. Turns out I'm wrong.

Comment: Looks like `su` isn't a builtin though, I shouldn't have removed that comment... OP, Inian's comment could help you solve your problem, but you'll have to use `/bin/su` rather than a plain `su`

Comment: Thanks @Inian it worked.

Comment: @emredmrl: I should have posted it as an answer! But you yourself beat me to it! :)

Comment: :) Btw, what is wrong with asking this question? Why people downwote? I sometimes cannot understand sw / cs community. I think beginner questions are not out of stackoverflow's scope.

Comment: @emredmrl the question would have been more appropriate on the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) StackExchanges, I guess that's the reason of the downvote (although simply voting to close the question as off-topic, as did 3 users, would have been more appropriate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `path` has been messed up and you will have to readd anything needed to your path.

This can be done by issuing the following command

`export PATH="$PATH:[directory to append to path]"`

in the case of the commands not found this path might get you going on the right path

`export PATH="$PATH:/bin"`

This however does not keep the `$PATH` value across reboots in which case the system file holding the path settings will need to be edited.